# How to remove gates added in the quantum circuit?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-circuit, programming

[image: Messed up circuit]

I am new to Qiskit and was learning Quantum teleportation circuit on youtube. I unknowingly executed a cell while trying to modify the circuit draw style which added the unnecessary gates. How can I remove them?

```
circuit.h(1)
circuit.cnot(1, 2)
circuit.draw(output="mpl")
```

This was the cell which I executed again.
I want to remove the gates after the second hadamard.

Comment: Just execute the cells again, starting from the first cell. And if you want to avoid this problem, make all the circuit construction code in one cell.

Comment: @Egretta.Thula aha. That helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your case, indeed, [rerun the cell in the best solution](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/31481/how-to-remove-gates-added-in-the-quantum-circuit#comment41622_31481).

Here, a general solution for situation when that is not possible. Say you have the following circuit and you would like to remove the first `CNOT`:

[image: A circuit with X in 0, a barrier, H 1, CX 1 2, and CX 0, 1]

In `QuantumCircuit.data`, there is a list of the instructions in the circuit. You can pretty-print-ish like this:

```python
for index, instruction in enumerate(circuit.data):
    print(index, instruction.operation.name, [ circuit.find_bit(q).index for q in instruction.qubits])
```

```
0 x [0]
1 barrier [0, 1, 2]
2 h [1]
3 cx [1, 2]
4 cx [0, 1]
```

You can directly remove an instructions by removing the entry in the `data` structure:

```
del circuit.data[3]
```

Resulting in the following circuit:

[image: A circuit with X in 0, a barrier, H 1, and CX 0, 1]